# Function argument default value on a ternary condition

Tags: php, function, ternary-operator, default-arguments

Trying to use the default value for argument of a function, but it always return as if the variable was null.

```
function a($param = "defaultValue") {
  echo( $param ? $param : 'Hello World');
  //echo( isset($param) ? $param : 'Hello World');
}


$pimba;
a($pimba);
```

I'm doing this to avoid doing it inside the function, like:

```
function a ($param) {
   $param = $param ? $param : 'defaultValue';
}
```

No idea why it's not working.
I want to avoid it because the code would be cleaner.

Comment: So what do you expect? `$pimba` is NULL.

Comment: *Unlike javascript, `$pimba;` is not variable declaration.*

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/UQZEf . `$pimba` is null, so that's what `$param` becomes. The declaration only assigns the value if you do not pass the variable in. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Comment: I want to get the default value from parameter line. `$param = "defaultValue"`.

Comment: @aynberOhh Ohh now I get it. `$param` will get the default value ONLY if no parameter is passed to the function OR if I pass `null` (not a variable set to null). Is that right?

Comment: No, only if you do not pass in the function. If you pass in NULL, `$param` will be NULL. See the 2nd line of the example in the doc link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

In php you have to remember that line `$pimba;` does nothing, there is no information what do you expect but I guess that `$pimba='';` is that what makes your code working as you expecting